# Remote Desktop Service - UnifiedSessionId is empty

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I've trouble with my Remote Desktop Service Sessions on Windows Server 2012R2. Get-RDUserSession command returns user with empty UnifiedSessionId. I want message to users, make shadown... But it's impossible without UnifiedSessionId.

Why UnifiedSessionId may be empty ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9492a3a1-b467-4e4b-978f-a4fdab681319/all-remote-desktop-sessions-in-my-farm-collection-are-0?forum=winserverTS

Answer by "keobr"

Answer (score 0):

The solution by keobr mentioned by Thibaut is what fixed it for me. I'll provide the info here though.
The Session Brokers need to be in the local security group for Remote Desktop Management on the Session Host servers. On each Session Host go to Computer Management, Local Users and Groups, Groups, then click on RDS Management Servers. Add your RDS Connection Brokers there. This was what I was missing that fixed the issue for me.
Also, the RDS Management Servers local group needs to be included on the security for TerminalServices under CIMV2 in WMI Control. Mine was there by default.
To check, In the search bar, type "Run" and run wmimgmt.msc
Right-Click WMI Control and go to properties.
On the Security tab, navigate to CIMV2, click on TerminalServices and click Security.
Make sure the local RDS Management Servers group is there.